# Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’ on Mac

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, cabal, quickcheck

When I try to test my code, IntelliJ gave me this error. However, I have used cabal install QuickCheck to install.

```
Testing.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Test.QuickCheck
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

Comment: Can you post the output when you install quickcheck?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
QuickCheck-2.10.0.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.

Comment: Does IntelliJ use a cabal sandbox? Also, if it's building the binary via cabal then the package might be hidden.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I don't think I'm using a cabal sandbox, I just followed regular instructions to install Haskell platform and cabal

Comment: Do you have QuickCheck listed as a build-dependency in your Cabal file?

Comment: @JackHenahan Yes I have I can see it and it is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is another instance of a nasty bug in the full release of the 8.2.1 Haskell-Platform binaries.

The solution is either to force reinstalls of the broken things, or simply to upgrade to the fixed release. More details were provided here: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-October/127979.html